# How can I keep tomatillos submerged in water during boiling?

Tags: boiling, mexican-cuisine

I like making enchiladas verdes, but I have an annoying time keeping tomatillos submerged when I boil them. The top part of them remain out of surface.

I try to keep them held down with a long wooden spoon. But I can't just stand there holding them for 5 to 10 minutes.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a metal wire strainer turned upside down in a larger cooking pot so that the tomatillos can bob around in the water but always be under the surface.  If for some reason the strainer doesn't stay down under the water, put some weight on the top.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong about tomatillos going up when you're boiling them. If this is causing tomatillos not getting completely cooked I would suggest to leave them a little bit more in a low fire until they're really soft. In my experience making enchiladas I know that the more cooked are the tomates the better is the flavour of the sauce.

Another thing you can do is to chop them in quarters so they can be cooked faster.